# Seemingly Unrelated Regression vs Systems OLS

Tags: least-squares

Could someone please clarify the relationship (if any) between SUR and SOLS? Is SOLS a method for estimating SUR? What are the differences between SUR and SOLS?

Also, is it true that these methods have an advantage over estimating these equations by OLS step by step, because we can get cross-equation relationships?

Comment: Can you spell out SOLS? What does it stand for?

Comment: It stands for Systems OLS

Answer (score 1):

Look for example William Greene's book Econometric Analysis.

Systems of equations need to be estimated jointly and only in special case, like in recursive system, can be OLS used without biases. Usually Full Information Maximum Likelihood and Limited Information Maximum Likelihood methods are used. They are quite similar as 2SLS and 3SLS.

SUR is a method of estimation for the system of equations when there is no endogenoity bias but disturbances across system can be related. This might be possible in examples like estimation of consumption system.

SUR is similar as generalized least squares estimation in single equation linear models where you believe homoskedasticity assumption cannot be met.